# how to fetch the data from Jquery Ajax POST request

Tags: jquery, ajax, laravel

i am trying to fetch data in my laravel controller function sent by Jquery Ajax POST request but i am unable to fetch the data and display.
This is the ajax request

```
 deleteImg=function(id)
{

    $.ajaxSetup({
        headers: {
            'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('meta[name="_token"]').attr('content')
        }
    });
    $.ajax({
        url: "/admin/gallery/deleteFile",
        method: 'POST',
        data:{'id':id},
        dataType:'JSON',
        contentType: false,
        cache: false,
        processData: false,
        success: function (res) {
            console.log(res);
        }
    });
}
```

and this is the controller method

```
public function deleteFile(Request $req)
{
    $id=$req->id;
    if($id)
    {
        die('done');
    }
    die('without');
}
```

and here is the route file

```
Route::get('gallery', 'GalleryController@index');
    Route::post('gallery/saveImage', 'GalleryController@saveImage');
    Route::get('gallery/getFiles', 'GalleryController@getFiles');
    Route::post('gallery/deleteFile', 'GalleryController@deleteFile');
```

It gives 'without' as the response. Can anybody tell me where i'm making a mistake. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Post your route plz

Comment: Kindly post the code of your routes, there must be some error.

Comment: Try `data: { id }` to send a request body like `id=123`

Comment: @PrabhjotSinghKainth if there would have been error in route file than it won't have responded 'without'. i have shared the route file though

Comment: @Utkarsh try to print_r($r) to check if it is receiving any data or not

Comment: @PrabhjotSinghKainth i tried using print_r($req) it returned an error of outofmemory, but i used print_r($req->all()) it returned an empty array. Like : Array(  )

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Send data like `Data: {"id" : id}` and also send csrf token for verification.

Check this out: https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/csrf for laravel csrf token.

**Edit :**

```
 var token = "<?php echo(csrf_token())?>";
    $.ajax({
        url: 'URL',
        type: 'POST',
        data: {id : val, _token : token},
        success: function(data){
           //todo     
        }
      });
```

It's worked for me.

Comment: i am including csrf token in my headers

Answer (score 0):

write your ajax code like this.

```
$.ajax
({
   type: "POST",
   url: "{{route('put your route here')}}",
   data: {"id":id,'_token': "{{ csrf_token() }}"},
   success: function(res)
   {
     console.log(res);
   }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know why but removing the `contentType: false, cache: false,processData: false,` from the request worked for me.

The ajax request looks like this now:

```
$.ajax({
        url: "/admin/gallery/deleteFile",
        method: 'POST',
        data:{"id":id},
        dataType:'JSON',
        success: function (res) {
            console.log(res);
        }
    });
```

and at backend controller i used `$id=$req->id` to store the id coming from the request

Answer (score -1):

You have to send data in JSON format, like data: {id: id}.

Comment: Right idea but that won't send JSON and I'm not even sure if it should

Comment: There is an issue with your ajax call. You can read about ajax call here: https://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/